# Javascript JSON.stringify / PHP json_decode Not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, stringify

I'm trying to send an array to PHP from JS.

JS:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(extraFields);
url += "&json="+json;
```

PHP:

```
$json = json_decode($_GET['json'], true);

foreach($json as $K=>$V){
    echo "json".$K . "=" . $V ."; ";
}
```

Assume `extraFields` is a valid array in this format:

```
extraFields['key1'] = 'val1';
extraFields['key2'] = 'val2';
extraFields['key3'] = 'val3';
```

The PHP error I'm getting is `invalid argument for Foreach`

When I loop through the `$_GET` values and just echo them, PHP shows empty brackets for `$_GET['json']` so it's recognizing it as json..

What am I doing wrong?

**Answer to TJ's comment**

```
var extraFields = new Array();
                var countFields = THIS.$_FIELDS.length;
                var Row = new Array();
                while(countFields--){
                    var name = THIS.$_FIELDS[countFields]['name'];
                    var id = THIS.$_FIELDS[countFields]['id'];
                    var elemVal = getElmVal(id);
                    extraFields[name] = elemVal;
                    window.alert(name +"="+ elemVal);
                }
```

Comment: Inspect the headers when sending from JS to your PHP, and when you use `json_decode`, inspect whether json_decode returned null. If it did, `echo json_last_error_msg();` to see what's wrong.

Comment: How are you *creating* `extraFields`? `= {}`? `= []`?

Comment: @Adelphia: That's part of the problem, then. You're using it as an object, not as an array, and the non-array properties won't be serialized. See item #2 in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You can't just dump JSON on the end of a URL and expect it to go through to the server correctly.

   At the very least, you have to URI-encode it:

   ```
   url += "&json="+encodeURIComponent(json);
   ```
2. The way you're using `extraFields` in your code snippet, it is **not** being used as an array. If you've created it as an array, those keys will not be serialized. The way you're using it, the correct way to create `extraFields` is:

   ```
   extraFields = {}; // NOT `= []` and NOT `= new Array()`
   ```

   That's an object, not an array. (Don't let the PHP term "associative array" fool you; that term is fairly PHP-specific and not related to the term "array" in the general sense. If you want arbitrary name/value pairs in JavaScript code, the term is "object" [or sometimes "map" or "dictionary", but they're objects].)

   If you add non-index properties to an array, `JSON.serialize` will ignore them (leave them out). Only use arrays (`[]`) with JSON for numerically-indexed data. Using objects (`{}`) for name/value pairs.

Comment: Thanks, TJ.. do you see a problem with using javascript's `escape()` instead?

Comment: @Adelphia: Yes; that's not what `escape` is for. `escape` has nothing whatsoever to do with URI-encoding.